# Now that posting to Friends wall with publish_stream will be deprecated, will it be possible to post to multiple friends at once?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ui

In the Facebook Developers Roadmap, October '13 breaking chances it says:

> **Removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API**
>
> We have found that posting content via API (stream.publish) on a friend's wall lead to a high incidence of user dissatisfaction (hiding content, blocking the app). After the migration period, posting content to friends' timelines via stream.publish will no longer be allowed. Please use the Feed Dialog for posting.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

They refer to the Feed Dialog as an alternative. I found that you can define at least one friend to post the message to, here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

> **to**:
> The ID or username of the profile that this story will be published to. If this is unspecified, it defaults to the value of from.

But did anybody find out how to post to multiple friends at once? And if so, in what format?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to post to multiple friends at once

You can not do this at once; you have to invoke the `feed dialog` for each friend in the loop.